# How do i float these two elements sharing a class, side by side?

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to float these two elements side to side so as to form a simple grid. I tried this from a SCSS tutorial but mine is having some issues, please help. From what I have tried they are floated in two rows. I just need one row and two columns.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1-of-2">
    col-1-of-2
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-of-2">
    col-1-of-2
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the SCSS

```
.row {
  max-width: 1400px;
  background-color: rgb(207, 207, 207);
  margin: 0 auto;
  &:not(:last-child) {
    //.row:not
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
  }

  .col-1-of-2 {
    width: calc((100%-3rem) / 2);
    background-color: orangered;
    float: left;
    &:not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: 3rem;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve it.

One quick and simple way is adding `display: flex` to the container and `flex-grow` to the child elements (I added padding and border only to make it more clear. As it's just css it works in SCSS as well).

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col-1-of-2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1-of-2">
    col-1-of-2
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-of-2">
    col-1-of-2
  </div>
</div>
```